# iOS can write but can’t read NFC tag

Tags: android, ios, tags, nfc

I’ve a strange problem, i bought some NFC Blank Card on amazon,

From my iPhone X i Tried to write contents using NFC Tools, but i wasn’t able to do That.

So i read on many forums That IOS can read only NDEF formatted tags,

So with an Android phone i formatted the card with NFC Tools,

Then in NFC Tools from my iPhone i was able to write a vcard on the NFC Card,

I can read it from my Android phone but in IOS Nothing happening, i can’t read the card even from the NFC Tools.. i can only write on it..

Comment: The tag is a MIFARE CLASSIC

Answer (score 1):

As a Mifare Classic card is a proprietary format and not to an NFC Standard, therefore they have limited compatibility.

On iOS at the hardware level with the latest version of iOS it does have the API capability to read/write to these cards but might not have support for automatic reading of these cards in iOS.

Also iOS does not support formatting these cards and NFC Tools say it only has partial support for these cards.

So you should be able to use the CoreNFC API's to write your own program to read and write to these Mifare Classic Cards.

Alternatively you use the [NFC TagWriter by NXP App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-tagwriter-by-nxp/id1246143221) on iOS as this will probably have better support for these Cards as NXP is the Manufacturer of them.

Though it would be best to not use these cards and use a card that conforms to one of the NFC standard like the NTAG21x range of tags.

Comment: Hi, any idea on how to transfer data from iphone to iphone which support nfc(say in latest iPhone)? I meant, i want write data on iPhone and want to read from another iPhone. Thanks